# High latency and inconcistency on all (if not most) wireless networks

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking, latency

Some time ago I reinstalled windows 10 on an HP Laptop (14-ac129la) because I installed an SSD. After three or four months after I installed the SSD, the owner started experiencing a constant slowdown of their web navigation. I dont know if this was gadual, but now its at the point of dropping ping packets to the local router, while being nexto to it. Pinging to 8.8.8.8 or 1.1.1.1, gives me some good latency times, but also some extremely high latencies compared to other devices (My main PC, and two other notebooks, all via WiFi).

I've tried the "reset network" thing aviable on windows 10, and after rebooting, it still has the same symptoms. This happens on multiple networs (I tested it on my home network, phone hotspot and a work network).

Forcing an static IP does not help. I'm totally lost, and i want to avoid having to reinstall windows again.

I will appreciate any help.
Thanks.

Here are some PING logs:

```
C:\Users\mpau7>ping 1.1.1.1 -t

Haciendo ping a 1.1.1.1 con 32 bytes de datos:
Respuesta desde 1.1.1.1: bytes=32 tiempo=72ms TTL=59
Respuesta desde 1.1.1.1: bytes=32 tiempo=91ms TTL=59
Respuesta desde 1.1.1.1: bytes=32 tiempo=90ms TTL=59
Respuesta desde 1.1.1.1: bytes=32 tiempo=60ms TTL=59
Respuesta desde 1.1.1.1: bytes=32 tiempo=718ms TTL=59
Respuesta desde 1.1.1.1: bytes=32 tiempo=266ms TTL=59
Respuesta desde 1.1.1.1: bytes=32 tiempo=319ms TTL=59
Respuesta desde 1.1.1.1: bytes=32 tiempo=348ms TTL=59
Respuesta desde 1.1.1.1: bytes=32 tiempo=82ms TTL=59
Respuesta desde 1.1.1.1: bytes=32 tiempo=74ms TTL=59
Respuesta desde 1.1.1.1: bytes=32 tiempo=116ms TTL=59
Respuesta desde 1.1.1.1: bytes=32 tiempo=263ms TTL=59
Respuesta desde 1.1.1.1: bytes=32 tiempo=44ms TTL=59
Respuesta desde 1.1.1.1: bytes=32 tiempo=67ms TTL=59
Respuesta desde 1.1.1.1: bytes=32 tiempo=218ms TTL=59
Respuesta desde 1.1.1.1: bytes=32 tiempo=78ms TTL=59
Respuesta desde 1.1.1.1: bytes=32 tiempo=145ms TTL=59
Respuesta desde 1.1.1.1: bytes=32 tiempo=58ms TTL=59
Respuesta desde 1.1.1.1: bytes=32 tiempo=90ms TTL=59
Respuesta desde 1.1.1.1: bytes=32 tiempo=280ms TTL=59
Respuesta desde 1.1.1.1: bytes=32 tiempo=1467ms TTL=59
Respuesta desde 1.1.1.1: bytes=32 tiempo=144ms TTL=59
Respuesta desde 1.1.1.1: bytes=32 tiempo=118ms TTL=59
Respuesta desde 1.1.1.1: bytes=32 tiempo=467ms TTL=59
Respuesta desde 1.1.1.1: bytes=32 tiempo=344ms TTL=59
Respuesta desde 1.1.1.1: bytes=32 tiempo=72ms TTL=59
Respuesta desde 1.1.1.1: bytes=32 tiempo=229ms TTL=59
Respuesta desde 1.1.1.1: bytes=32 tiempo=63ms TTL=59
Respuesta desde 1.1.1.1: bytes=32 tiempo=441ms TTL=59

Estadísticas de ping para 1.1.1.1:
    Paquetes: enviados = 29, recibidos = 29, perdidos = 0
    (0% perdidos),
Respuesta desde 1.1.1.1: Tiempos aproximados de ida y vuelta en milisegundos:
    Mínimo = 44ms, Máximo = 1467ms, Media = 235ms
bytes=32 Control-C
^C
C:\Users\mpau7>ping 8.8.8.8 -t

Haciendo ping a 8.8.8.8 con 32 bytes de datos:
Respuesta desde 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 tiempo=259ms TTL=59
Respuesta desde 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 tiempo=61ms TTL=59
Respuesta desde 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 tiempo=98ms TTL=59
Respuesta desde 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 tiempo=47ms TTL=59
Tiempo de espera agotado para esta solicitud.
Respuesta desde 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 tiempo=30ms TTL=59
Respuesta desde 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 tiempo=168ms TTL=59
Respuesta desde 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 tiempo=507ms TTL=59
Respuesta desde 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 tiempo=356ms TTL=59
Respuesta desde 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 tiempo=366ms TTL=59
Respuesta desde 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 tiempo=258ms TTL=59
Respuesta desde 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 tiempo=181ms TTL=59
Respuesta desde 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 tiempo=75ms TTL=59
Respuesta desde 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 tiempo=297ms TTL=59
Respuesta desde 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 tiempo=357ms TTL=59
Respuesta desde 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 tiempo=127ms TTL=59
Respuesta desde 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 tiempo=110ms TTL=59
Respuesta desde 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 tiempo=252ms TTL=59
Respuesta desde 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 tiempo=171ms TTL=59
Respuesta desde 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 tiempo=272ms TTL=59
Respuesta desde 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 tiempo=146ms TTL=59
Respuesta desde 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 tiempo=599ms TTL=59
Respuesta desde 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 tiempo=447ms TTL=59
Respuesta desde 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 tiempo=797ms TTL=59
Respuesta desde 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 tiempo=140ms TTL=59
Respuesta desde 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 tiempo=362ms TTL=59
Respuesta desde 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 tiempo=94ms TTL=59
Respuesta desde 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 tiempo=29ms TTL=59
Respuesta desde 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 tiempo=84ms TTL=59

Estadísticas de ping para 8.8.8.8:
    Paquetes: enviados = 29, recibidos = 28, perdidos = 1
    (3% perdidos),
Tiempos aproximados de ida y vuelta en milisegundos:
    Mínimo = 29ms, Máximo = 797ms, Media = 238ms
Control-C
^C
C:\Users\mpau7>ping 192.168.1.1 -t

Haciendo ping a 192.168.1.1 con 32 bytes de datos:
Respuesta desde 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 tiempo=227ms TTL=64
Respuesta desde 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 tiempo=68ms TTL=64
Respuesta desde 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 tiempo=330ms TTL=64
Respuesta desde 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 tiempo=54ms TTL=64
Respuesta desde 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 tiempo=105ms TTL=64
Respuesta desde 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 tiempo=79ms TTL=64
Respuesta desde 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 tiempo=35ms TTL=64
Respuesta desde 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 tiempo=41ms TTL=64
Respuesta desde 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 tiempo=44ms TTL=64
Respuesta desde 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 tiempo=61ms TTL=64
Respuesta desde 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 tiempo=10ms TTL=64
Respuesta desde 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 tiempo=51ms TTL=64
Respuesta desde 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 tiempo=40ms TTL=64
Respuesta desde 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 tiempo=35ms TTL=64
Respuesta desde 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 tiempo=44ms TTL=64
Respuesta desde 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 tiempo=52ms TTL=64
Respuesta desde 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 tiempo=18ms TTL=64
Respuesta desde 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 tiempo=14ms TTL=64
Respuesta desde 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 tiempo=39ms TTL=64
Respuesta desde 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 tiempo=789ms TTL=64
Respuesta desde 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 tiempo=44ms TTL=64
Respuesta desde 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 tiempo=45ms TTL=64
Respuesta desde 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 tiempo=63ms TTL=64
Respuesta desde 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 tiempo=23ms TTL=64
Respuesta desde 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 tiempo=19ms TTL=64
Respuesta desde 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 tiempo=31ms TTL=64
Respuesta desde 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 tiempo=35ms TTL=64
Respuesta desde 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 tiempo=35ms TTL=64
Respuesta desde 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 tiempo=18ms TTL=64

Estadísticas de ping para 192.168.1.1:
    Paquetes: enviados = 29, recibidos = 29, perdidos = 0
    (0% perdidos),
Tiempos aproximados de ida y vuelta en milisegundos:
    Mínimo = 10ms, Máximo = 789ms, Media = 84ms
Respuesta desde 192.168.1.1: Control-C
^C
```

Comment: Are there drivers for the WiFi? (Note: There are *always* drivers but typically they're included in Windows; the device or the chipset manufacturer my provide different ones nevertheless) If so try installing them. Other possibility is one of the antennae not working/disconnected or damaged.

Comment: The drivers used are the ones provided by HP. Also, if the signal strength is good, and similar to other devices in similar circumstances, could it still be the wifi antenna?